# Binwalk and firmware of a sat receiver

Tags: firmware

i'm tried to gather information of firmware and extract the contain with binwalk on kali , when i scanned rom.bin , i have as result many lines 1-> most of lines are LZMA data compressed , but when i extract this data i can't open it. 2-> last line "Mcrypte 2.2 , blofish crypted"

can some help me , what can i do to extract data correctly

here the firmware
http://wikisend.com/download/396604/rom.bin http://wikisend.com/download/194102/ChannelList.bin

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably obfuscated:
[read more about an obfuscated firmware from WRT120N](http://www.devttys0.com/2014/02/reversing-the-wrt120n-firmware-obfuscation/)

I think that you should do hardware analysis in order to know how the firmware is unpacked...